# How would I go about making stacked area chart with overlapping areas?

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, stacked-area-chart

I would like to make an area chart like this:
[image]
with [d3.js](http://www.d3js.org) javascript library. Is this possible?

I know it is possible to do this with the Google Visualization API, see [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984981/903186)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just need a path element that defines each block, and to specify a [fill opacity](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillOpacityProperty)